# java programming loop not working

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

```
public void listAllFiles() {
    for (String filename: files) {
        int position = 0;
        System.out.println(position + ": " + filename);
        position = position + 1;
    }
}
```

The loop above displays elements from an `ArrayList files`. I want to display the index as well as the string elements within the lists. However, when the method is called, the index always prints as "0".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place

```
int position = 0;
```

before the loop, else it will always be `0` each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

You're initialising `position` to zero inside the loop. That means it will always be zero at that point in the loop.

Initialise it before the loop.

```
int position = 0;
for (String filename : files){
    System.out.println(position + ": " + filename);
    ++position;
}
```